# Sending automatic emails with java

Tags: java, email

I need to send automatic emails every certain time from my spring mvc application.
I have been researching some tools like

- quartz
- ScheduledExecutorService
- ScheduledFuture
- Timer
- TimerTask

My question is that i need to send those emails even if the pc is turned off, i suppose that i have some kind of server in my work if this task cant not be done by only using my application.
If that is the case what should i do to my server to make this task?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a server, you just need to deploy your spring application with a scheduler. here are the [examples](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/23/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/)

configure the time when you want to send the [email](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/sending-e-mail-with-spring-mvc), the server needs to be running to complete its scheduler task.

Comment: ok so is there no other way to do this task without a server?, if theres a option to do this task without having to touch the server would be better, is there a chance to do it without a server? i mean just running my application in the pc and even with the pc is turned off the emails are going to be sent

Comment: if the pc is turned off who will trigger the email?

Comment: what i want to do is to have a config menu where you can choose: "i want to send these email in an automatic way every 5 days", but if the computer if turned off the day when the email is going to be sent, the email needs to be sent anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple method would be to integrate your e-mail script into a cron job in which you specify an time interval to execute your script.

[One line cron job script](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

A really great API which empowers developers to send emails is called [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com). [Zapier](https://zapier.com/how-it-orks/) complements Mailgun really well, and allows you to schedule tasks to fire off when ever you choose. [This](https://zapier.com/zapbook/mailgun/schedule/) article demonstrates how developers have integrated Zapier and Mail Gun. Both these services have a free tier which is pretty reasonable for small to mid-sized projects which your office's internal tool might fall under.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: hi friend, does this APIs can send those emails even if the PC is turned off.

Comment: hi friend, yep! the API works of an remote SMTP server that is owned by Mailgun, so it'll send it whenever you schedule it to be sent!